# Why do this give an empty "{}"?

Tags: list-manipulation

Table[x/(x + 1), {x, 2.5, 1.999, 0.000001}]

Hello, i am trying to make a table of values for this function in steps of 0.000001, but once i use Shift+Enter, the result is just an empty interval "{}". What is wrong? I am using the syntax of the  Wolfram Reference web.
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the syntax for `Table` you will find this,

> `Table[expr,{i,Subscript[i, min], Subscript[i, max], di}}]`

where, `Subscript[i, min]` is the starting point of the interval and  `Subscript[i, max]` is the end point.

Thus the correct way is,

```
Table[x/(x + 1), {x, 1.999, 2.5, 0.000001}]
```

Comment: Either that, or `Table[expr, {x, 2.5, 1.999, -0.000001}]` if you absolutely need to go backwards.